# adding value to dictionary based on other values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary with large number of keys and each key has 15 values. 
Below is sample of dictionary

```
city_info = {
    'new york': {
        'bus': 4175000,
        'car': 2869717,
        'income avg': 3081055,
        'pop': 40000000,
    },
    'memphis': {
        'bus': 4175000,
        'car': 2869717,
        'income avg': 3081055,
        'pop': 400000,
    },
}
```

There are 800+ cities or keys in it. 
What I would like to do is basically, add value which is ratio other value so the above dictionary would additional value called "bus ratio" which ratio of pop/bus value.

So, new dictionary would look like

```
city_info_new = {
    'new york': {
        'bus': 4175000,
        'car': 2869717,
        'income avg': 3081055,
        'pop': 40000000,
        'bus_ratio': 9.58,
    },
    'memphis': {
        'bus': 4175000,
        'car': 2869717,
        'income avg': 3081055,
        'pop': 400000,
        'bus_ratio': 0.095,
    },
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over all dictionary values and add the new field `bus_ratio`:

```
for value in city_info.values():
    value['bus_ratio'] = value['pop'] / value['bus']
```

Comment: Thanks. simple, concise, and works. I just had add float to denominator to stop from getting zero values less 1. value['bus_ratio'] = value['pop'] / float(value['bus'])

Comment: I am just running to situation where some of 'pop' or 'bus' value are 'NaN' or string and division produces an error.

Answer (score 3):

To create an entirely new dictionary, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
city_info = {
'new york': {
    'bus': 4175000,
    'car': 2869717,
    'income avg': 3081055,
    'pop': 40000000,
},
'memphis': {
    'bus': 4175000,
    'car': 2869717,
    'income avg': 3081055,
    'pop': 400000,
 },
}
city_info_new = {a:{**b, 'bus_ratio':round(b['pop']/float(b['bus']), 2)} for a, b in city_info.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'new york': {'bus': 4175000, 'car': 2869717, 'income avg': 3081055, 'pop': 40000000, 'bus_ratio': 9.58}, 'memphis': {'bus': 4175000, 'car': 2869717, 'income avg': 3081055, 'pop': 400000, 'bus_ratio': 0.1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
def Ratio(city):
    return city['pop']/city['bus']

for city,vals in city_info.items():
    vals['bus_ratio']=Ratio(vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) here:

```
for city in city_info:
    ratio = city_info[city]['pop'] / city_info[city]['bus']
    city_info[city].update({'bus_ratio': ratio})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dictionary keys like this:

```
for city in city_info:
    city_info[city]['bus_ratio'] = city_info[city]['pop'] / city_info[city]['bus']
```